# List of Time Zones in Java

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, timezone

I am using below code to generate a time zone list with Offset.

```
public static List<String> TimeZonesCollectionUTC(OffsetType type)
{
    List<String> timezonesList = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> zoneIds = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    zoneIds.forEach((zoneId) ->
    {
        timezonesList.add("(" + type + now.atZone(ZoneId.of(zoneId))
                .getOffset().getId().replace("Z", "+00:00") + ") " + zoneId);
    });
    return timezonesList;
}
```

The issue is it provides me 600+ time zones. But expectation is to get a user friendly time zone list with less number of list or group it on some rules.
Need some help here to create a custom list of time zone in Java with daylight saving also taken care
TIA

Comment: How about asking the user for an offset first, then only show timezones currently at that offset/time zones with that offset as the standard offset?

Comment: I don't have that privilege, But I fixed offset as UTC

Comment: What I meant was to group it on the standard offset (since you said "group it on some rules") What do you mean you don't have that privilege?

Comment: If you group by standard offset, the largest group is only about 50 zones. Is that a "user-friendly" list for you?

Comment: @Sweeper that would address my issue, Can you help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group the timezones by their current offsets. The user would choose their current offset first, and then all the timezones that currently have that offset would be shown.

```
var timezoneGroups = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
        .map(ZoneId::of)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getRules().getOffset(Instant.now())));
```

Alternatively, group by `getStandardOffset(Instant.now())` if you think your users are going to be more familiar with those.

This gives you a `Map<ZoneOffset, List<ZoneId>>`. Here is an example of printing it to the command line:

```
// sort the offsets first...
timezoneGroups.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .forEach(entry -> {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        for (var zone: entry.getValue()) {
            System.out.print("    ");
            System.out.println(zone.getId());
        }
    });
```

Example output:

```
...
-01:00
    Etc/GMT+1
    Atlantic/Cape_Verde
    Atlantic/Azores
    America/Scoresbysund
-02:00
    Etc/GMT+2
    America/Noronha
    Brazil/DeNoronha
    Atlantic/South_Georgia
-03:00
    America/Miquelon
    America/Argentina/Catamarca
    America/Argentina/Cordoba
    America/Araguaina
    America/Argentina/Salta
...
```